# 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): You are being rate limited

Tags: discord.py

I have a public bot that is in 150+ servers and I got a

> 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): You are being rate limited.

from one user who spammed the blackjack command.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening? My blackjack command has already a cooldown of 10 sec and also is being rate limited only applies to the user who got the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is a person that is repetitively "spamming" a command, add a cooldown. If the cooldown is already implemented, increase the time for the cooldown. Or, in fact, you can blacklist the person from using your command:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.user)
async def foo(ctx):
    if ctx.message.author == 'Spammer#1234':
        await ctx.send('You have been blacklisted from this command due to repetitive spamming.')
        return
    else:
        # Your code here
```

> Unfortunately, there is no way to "revoke" a rate-limit. You will have to wait the time being.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. Edited my question. What bothers me is if it will affect my bot or just the user who spammed that’s being rate limited.

Comment: The cooldown will be for all users regardless. But the blacklisting will be only for the members that are specified, like `Spammer#1234`. Unfortunately, the rate-limit will not allow the bot to run, which means that the whole bot will be unable to function.